# Python 3.x print number of lines after a specific header

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, printing

I have an issuse I can't seem to resolve; apologies if this is duplicate but never came a across a real answer. I'm extracting specific info from a configuration file that displays information in blocks of text and I need to print only specific blocks, without the heading. So for example (with the text format below) I would only want to capture the information below Header2 but not anything past header 3:

```
#   output could containmultiple headers, and lines, or no lines per header this is an example of what could be present but it is not absolute. 

header1
-------
line1
line2
line3 # can be muiplies availables or known

header2
-------
line1
line2
line3 # can be muiplies availables or known

header3
-------

header4
-------
line1
line2
line3 # can be multiple linnes or none not known
```

Here is the code that I started with but the stuck on the second loop boolean or logic for to print only the lines of that header block:

```
Raw_file = "scrap.txt"
scrape = open(Raw_file,"r") 


for fooline in scrape:

        if "Header" in fooline:
                #print(fooline) # prints all lines
                    #print lines under header 2 and stop before header 3



scrape.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the detection of header lines to turn on/off a boolean that controls printing:

```
RAW_FILE = "scrap.txt"

DESIRED = 'header2'

with open(RAW_FILE) as scrape:

    printing = False

    for line in scrape:

        if line.startswith(DESIRED):
            printing = True
        elif line.startswith('header'):
            printing = False
        elif line.startswith('-------'):
            continue
        elif printing:
            print(line, end='')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
line1
line2
line3 # can be muiplies availables or known

>
```

Tweak as needed.

Comment: This is excellent thanks, if I also wanted to print an object in the line, how would I do that. I tried splitting it and printing line[0] to get the '3'. line sample = "3 man  enable none"  but no luck keeps returning a no object maybe I'm not understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a regex to break this into blocks.

If the file is of manageable size, just read it all at once and use a regex like:

```
(^header\d+[\s\S]+?(?=^header|\Z))
```

to break it into blocks. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNXiJl/1/)

Then your Python code would look like this (to get any text between the headers):

```
import re

with open(fn) as f:
    txt=f.read()

for m in re.finditer(r'(^header\d+[\s\S]+?(?=^header|\Z))', txt, re.M):
    print(m.group(1))
```

If the file is bigger than what you want to read in one gulp, you can use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mmap.html) with a regex and read a file in blocks of considerable size.

If you are looking for only a single header, it is even easier:

```
m=re.search(r'(^header2[\s\S]+?(?=^header|\Z))', txt, re.M)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

[Demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/7dg1iH/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag that starts and stops collection, based on matching `header2` and `header3` content.

With `example.txt` containing the full example data provided:

```
f = "example.txt"
scrape = open(f,"r") 

collect = 0
wanted = []

for fooline in scrape:
    if "header2" in fooline:
        collect = 1
    if "header3" in fooline:
        collect = 2

    if collect == 1:
        wanted.append(fooline)
    elif collect == 2:
        break

scrape.close()
```

`wanted` output:

```
['header2\n',
 '-------\n',
 'line1\n',
 'line2\n',
 'line3 # can be muiplies availables or known\n',
 '\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, set `flag` to `False`. Check if the line begins with `header2`. If `True`, set `flag`. If the line begins with `header3`, set `flag` to `False`.

Print the lines if `flag` is set.

```
Raw_file = "scrap.txt"
scrape = open(Raw_file,"r") 
flag = False

for fooline in scrape:
    if fooline.find("header3") == 0: flag = False # or break
    if flag:
        print(fooline)
    if fooline.find("header2") == 0: flag = True
scrape.close()
```

Output:

```
-------

line1

line2

line3 # can be muiplies availables or known
```